# Error while implementing Geojson in React Native

Tags: react-native, geojson, react-native-maps

I am trying to implement a `Geojson` layer on a map in React-Native.

Development environment:

- react-native-maps: 0.24.2,
- expo: 33.0.0

I have tried the following three methods without success:

1. Overlay
2. Polygon and icon (using image)
3. `Geojson`

I feel `Geojson` is the simplest and direct method of implementing this layer on a map (Apple Maps for iOS and Google Maps for Android). Geojson method is unfortunately not working.

I don't know how to create a codesandbox for React Native but you will find my code snippet below.

```
displayLightPollutionLayer() {
  const features = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "artificialNightSkyBrightness_example",
    "crs": { 
      "type": "name", 
      "properties": 
        { 
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" 
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {  
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": 
            { 
              "Name": null, 
              "description": null, 
              "drawOrder": 15, 
              "icon": "https:\/\/nightskybrightness.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com\/ArtificialSkyBrightness537.JPG" 
            }, 
          "geometry": 
            { 
              "type": "Polygon", 
              "coordinates": [ 
                [ 
                  [4.2499263, 50.937513844500003], 
                  [4.2499263, 42.404183924500003], 
                  [-4.12507035, 42.404183924500003], 
                  [-4.12507035, 50.937513844500003], 
                  [4.2499263, 50.937513844500003] 
                ] 
              ] 
            } 
        }
      ]
  }

  return (
    <Geojson geojson={features}/>
  )
}
```

**Error:**

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>   Check the render method of `LightPollutionAtlas`.

**Expected result:**

The images should be positioned all over the map at predefined coordinates and should be zoomable.

Comment: react or react-native?

Comment: The problem is in React Native. I have successfully done it in React for the web using a KML layer but I am not being able to do it in React Native for mobile devices.

Comment: You are using wrong lib, you have to use, react-native-maps not react-google-maps
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps

Comment: I am using react-native-maps. The codesandbox example is the just to demonstrate what the final result should like.

Comment: update your question with proper links of the libs you r using, like geojson

Comment: I have mentioned the library and version I am using and I have removed the link to the codesandbox that was useful to understand what the final result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem. As of today in react-native-maps v0.24.2, Geojson doesn't render images. As per my understanding, Geojson component in react-native-maps renders only points, polygons and polylines. I thus switched to Overlay component to position images at predefined coordinates on the map (Apple Maps for iOS). I haven't tested the solution yet for Google Maps on Android but I believe it should work fine.

I have separated the code into two components : 
1. Creation of Overlays.
2. Creation of Map View that incorporates the above overlays.

```
class PollutionOverlay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <View>

        <Overlay
        image={{ uri: 'valid URI'}}
        bounds={[[50.9375138445,-4.12507035],[42.4041839245,4.2499263]]}
        />

        <Overlay
        image={{ uri: 'valid URI`enter code here`'}}
        bounds={[[50.9375138445,4.2499263],[42.4041839245,12.62492295]]}
        />

      </View>

    )
  }
}

export default PollutionOverlay;

-------------------------------------

import PollutionOverlay from 'valid path';
class LightPollutionAtlas extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

render() {


  return(
      <MapView
      style={styles.mapStyle}
      maxZoomLevel={9}
      >

      <PollutionOverlay />

      </MapView>

  )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapStyle: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

export default LightPollutionAtlas;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Geojson` is a component of 'react-native-geojson' module. So you need to import that module, add this line on top of your class.

```
import Geojson from 'react-native-geojson';
```

Also "if haven't already", run `npm install react-native-geojson`, Inside your project folder.

Also as I have noticed (maybe I am wrong) `Geojson` doesn't support Images directly so, one thing that you can try is to add this code in return of `displayLightPollutionLayer` function:

```
return (
  <Geojson geojson={features}>
          <Image source="https:\/\/nightskybrightness.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com\/ArtificialSkyBrightness537.JPG" style = {{flex:1}}/>
  </Geojson>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `displayLightPollutionLayer` function as follows, to draw the polygon,

```
displayLightPollutionLayer(markers) {
const features = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "name": "artificialNightSkyBrightness_example",
      "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": 
      "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Name": null,
            "description": null,
            "drawOrder": 15,
            "icon": "https:\/\/nightskybrightness.s3.eu-west- 3.amazonaws.com\/ArtificialSkyBrightness537.JPG"
          },
          "geometry": { 
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [ 4.2499263, 50.937513844500003 ],
                [ 4.2499263, 42.404183924500003 ],
                [ -4.12507035, 42.404183924500003 ],
                [ -4.12507035, 50.937513844500003 ],
                [ 4.2499263, 50.937513844500003 ]
              ]
            ]
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
   return (<Polygon
      coordinates={this.getCoordinates(features)}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
    />);
}

getCoordinates(features) {
     let updatedFeatures = features.features[0].geometry.coordinates.map((coordinate) => {latitude: coordinate[0], longitude: coordinate[1]});
     return updatedFeatures;
}

render() {
    return (
<MapView
  region={this.state.region}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
  {this.displayLightPollutionPolygonLayer()}
</MapView>
)
}
```

I have updated the logic, please add all necessary validations to avoid unwanted crashes.

Comment: Hello Gokul, Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. If we use a Polygon, we will not be able to render an image. That is why I am using Geojson. Like I clearly indicated in my question, I need to render an image at predefined coordinates. Just like the example I had mentioned in the question initially. Thanks for trying anyways.